# changed CMakeCache.txt to changed new version

Tags: cmake, version, new-operator, cmake-gui

i want to i changed directly in a line in CMakeChache.txt

"CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=/usr/share/cmake-3.10"
to
"CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=/usr/local/bin/cmake "

but it was changed by default as well. 
how to make it permanent.?

thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's virtually never necessary to change anything in CMakeChache.txt, so i think you are trying to solve your initial problem on a wrong way. Could you please describe what is your original problem?

Comment: Meaning of [CMAKE_ROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_ROOT.html) variable is a **directory** containing `Modules/` subdirectory with modules shipped with the CMake itself. Assigning this variable a **file** `/usr/local/bin/cmake` is opposite to this meaning and thus has a little sense.